# kernel c multiple definiton of function error

Tags: android, c, compiler-errors, linux-kernel

I'm currently trying to compile kernel for my android device
unfortunatly I faced with this compilation error and stuck with it

compiler says:

```
drivers/dpram/built-in.o:(.bss+0x2815c): multiple definition of `pm_dev'
drivers/net/built-in.o:(.bss+0x1ac4): first defined here
```

in drivers/dpram.c ı have:

```
struct device *pm_dev;

    pm_dev = device_create(sec_class, NULL, 0, NULL, "pm");
    if(IS_ERR(pm_dev))
        pr_err("Failed to create device(pm)!\n");
    if(device_create_file(pm_dev, &dev_attr_info) < 0)
        pr_err("Failed to create device file(%s)!\n", dev_attr_info.attr.name);
    if(device_create_file(pm_dev, &dev_attr_power_down) < 0)
        pr_err("Failed to create device file(%s)!\n", dev_attr_power_down.attr.name);
```

and in drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/bcmsdh_linux.c ı have:

```
struct device *pm_dev;

    if (!device_init_wakeup(dev, 1))
        pm_dev = dev;

    if (pm_dev) {
        device_init_wakeup(pm_dev, 0);
        pm_dev = NULL;
    }
```

I'm currently trying to figure it out but ı couldnt yet

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because

```
struct device *pm_dev;
```

is a *definition* in C. It defines a pointer to structure `device` and it's name is `pm_dev`. It is not allowed to define variable more than once therefore you should declare `pm_dev` as **extern** in all other source files but just one in which you actually define it.

Declaration(s):

```
extern struct device *pm_dev;
```

Single definition:

```
struct device *pm_dev;
```

Comment: so should i check all source and convert all the pm_dev definitions (struct device *pm_dev; --> extern struct device *pm_dev;)

Comment: Alrigth I converted pm_dev definitions in both dpram.c and bcmsdh_linux.c files but now ı got "Undefined reference to pm_dev" error in dpram.o

Comment: hmm strange... I converted pm_dev definition in only bcmsdh_linux.c file and didnt touch dpram.c file....now it is compiling good...do you think did ı make mistake? is it a good way?

Comment: Isn't it just a *declaration*, or particularly a *forward declaration*? Definition in my understanding should look like an assignment.

Comment: int i; as well as int *pi; in C and C++ is definition. There is no such thing as fwd declaration in standard. It is a rule that says "A declaration is a definition unless it [...] is a class name declaration [...]." (3.1/2, C++03) that   is used as what fwd declaration is.

Comment: yeah ı solved the compilation error as ı said above but couldnt try to verify it yet if it is working or not.. will inform you when ı tested it..thanx again man